# Is there a third option for $.ajax other than done and fail?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a suspicion that every once in a while, my $.ajax call doesn't return with either a done or a fail. Is that possible? That it just doesn't return at all?

The reason I suspect is because I mark the rows that I've sent to the server as being sent, and some of them are being sent twice.

Comment: that'd fall under timeout, which would fall under the fail umbrella

Answer (score 5):

jQuery supports:

```
.done()
.fail()
.always()
.then()
```

> I have a suspicion that every once in a while, my $.ajax call doesn't
>   return with either a done or a fail. Is that possible? That it just
>   doesn't return at all?

Unless there's some exception somewhere in your code or jQuery code that aborts execution of an expected code path, then it is not supposed to be possible that neither `.done()` or `.fail()` gets called.  **One or the other should get called.**

`.always()` is called along with either `.done()` or `.fail()`.

`.then()` accepts two callback functions and is the promise-standard replacement for `.done()` and `.fail()`.

There are some older, deprecated functions like `.success()`, but they don't affect how `.done()` or `.fail()` work.

Comment: Wait: so I should be using `then` instead of `done` & `fail`? I replaced `success` with `done` awhile ago.

Comment: @JohnCena - I only use `.then()` myself. jQuery is working on making their promises completely compatible with the ES6 promises spec for a future version and that is `.then()` so I only program with `.then()` in the interest of future compatibility and ES6 familiarity.  They probably won't remove `.done()` or `.fail()` for a long while, but I wouldn't be surprised if they get deprecated at some point.